# createHtmlOutputFromFile then append variable as an object from the function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to pass all values from `Google Sheets` to `HTML` (Google web app) by using Google-Apps-Script `doGet()` and append in the script to keep as global variable. Faster than html load first then use `google.run.script...` in my opinion

So getting an object `key as a sheet_name` and `key values as 2D_array data`

```
function getSheetData() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  var object = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    object[sheets[i].getName()] = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues().filter(r => r[0] !== '')
  }
  return object
}
```

in function doGet() I'm using `append` to add the script to the HTML

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Main')
  html.append('<script> var userData = ' + getSheetData() + ' </script>')
  return html
}
```

Still getting `<script> var userData = [object Object] </script>`

it should be something like `<script> var userData = {key1:[2D Array],key2:[2D Array]} </script>`

I also tried with `string` and it works fine. But can we possibly do as an object?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A fallacy with your idea is that all communication between the client and server is initated by the client.  So passing data to html can only happen once and only when you are evaulating a templated html solution.

Comment: I use the container for container bound scripts to contain globals and I store them as a hash table in a sheet I always name as Globals and I as special set of functions for getting and setting the global variables.   But I wouldn't wont to have to wait to polled by the client before I can get my variable and I also wouldn't really want to store some on the variable clientside any for security reasons.

Comment: *Faster than html load first then use google.run.script... in my opinion* More than likely, Your opinion is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper I'd get your advice, could be useful for me. And thanks both of you to correct my opinion, I need to learn more about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> html.append(' var userData = ' + getSheetData() + ' ')

When appending html,  the script is appending a [`string`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendaddedcontent).  The `object` returned by `getSheetData()` is coerced to a `string` implicitly, when using the `+` operator. The coercion doesn't produce a full array as `string` but just as `[object Object]`.

To bypass this, you may use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) server side:

```
html.append('<script> var userData = ' + JSON.stringify(getSheetData()) + ' </script>')
```

Comment: Only `...userData = ' + JSON.stringify(getSheetData()) + '...` work fine for me. And importantly I know more about `JSON` stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @zummontt  I take back what I said: `parse` isn't necessary. Do you get any errors if you use `parse`?

Comment: I'm afraid to say yes, it shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` then I thought in term of using the stored variable I don't need those `JSON.parse` part

Comment: @zummontt Thank you for the confirmation.  I edited my answer to reflect your inputs. Thank you.